I have a 07 Honda fit. It will start when it's cold. Once the engine warms up it won't start
2007 Honda fit GD3. Don't start after reaching at operating temperature. It cranks. it almost acts like a dead battery. It will make  clicking noise like a dead battery. All the dash lights and everything look and sound normal. Jumping it don't start it either. No check engine light or any other codes.also has high pitched sound coming from engine bay. The sound is there when the car is running it will continue once the car is shut off if the key is on.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
